# New instance of an arbitrary class

Tags: java, class, constructor

In Java, how can I create a new instance of a class, where the class is not selected until the code is run?

```
List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<>();
classes.add(String.class);
classes.add(ArrayList.class);
classes.add(Integer.class);
classes.add(Random.class);

Random r = new Random();
Class c = classes.get(r.nextInt(classes.size()));

Object o = // new instance of "c"
```

Comment: `c.newInstance()` provided default constructor

Comment: @JigarJoshi: What was that?  Could be a good answer, if you provided a code sample.

Comment: @JigarJoshi Right.. but `new String()` won't help you much.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29 @Robert

Comment: @JigarJoshi Well if you get `Integer.class`, you're unlucky with that.

Comment: @Ypnypn You'll probably get more helpful answers if you motivate your need for instantiating arbitrary classes. That is not to say that your requirement is a wrong one but there may be other ways to go about doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the class has a no-arg constructor you can just call `c.newInstance()`.  Otherwise you need to call the overloaded version of `newInstance()` which accepts arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Try in this way but not a good way.

```
Class<?> clazz = String.class;
Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { "abc" });

System.out.println(object); // print abc
```

Comment: Object java.lang.Class.newInstance() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException

Deprecated. This method propagates any exception thrown by the nullary constructor, including a checked exception. Use of this method effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that would otherwise be performed by the compiler. The Constructor.newInstance method avoids this problem by wrapping any exception thrown by the constructor in a (checked) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.